# System requirement for TFS 2012 Express

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I just want to know

Is **TFS 2012 EXPRESS** is compatible with **SQL SERVER 2008 ENTERPRISE** edition and **OS** is window **SERVER 2012**

And possible then what would be the process to install it.

Thanks

Comment: Usually system requirements and installation procedures are well documented, e.g. [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29035).

Answer (score 1):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd631889.aspx):

SQL 2008 Enterprise is supported but it must be SQL 2008 R2 with Service Pack 1.

TFS requires Windows Server 2008 (SP2, or R2 SP1) and will need to be on a 64 bit OS for the server side, but 32 bit clients can access it.

The set up is pretty self explanatory, I had a [problem](https://serverfault.com/questions/432496/cannot-create-a-project-tfs-2012-tf218027) getting the permissions right, if you get a choice of letting TFS setup the database alongside the TFS implementation choose that, it is simpler. It can be done with an existing database though.